# How can I send simple message to my website's php from Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Im trying to send simple login/password parameters to my PHP file in my server from my simple Chrome extension. The code below gives me an "is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin". What can I do to send simple parameters and receive the echo from the php?

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "http://mywebsite/api.php?u=admin&p=admin", true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (xhr.readyState == 4) {

alert(xhr.responseText);
}
}
xhr.send();
```

What are some ways to contact my server and pass simple parameters and get responses from a google extension?

EDIT
    "permissions": ["contextMenus","http://mywebsite/"],

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing a cross-origin XMLHttpRequest, so you need to set up some extra permissions for your extension. See [this](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/xhr.html).

In your `manifest.json` file add:

```
  "permissions": [
    "http://mywebsite/"
  ]
```

Remember to reload your extension after these changes.

Comment: Well I added this to my manifest but it still didn't help me :/
See my edit up top

Comment: Have you reloaded your extension after changes in `manifest.json`?

Comment: Oh I see now I did not reload the whole extension